# Unable to connect to MongoDB using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I installed MongoDB in my machine and I'm able to start mongod and connect to the db using the mongo command. I even imported some data in the `mycol` collection of the `mydb` db:

```
$ sudo start mongodb
mongodb start/running, process 31008
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
> db.mycol.count();
5730
> ^C
bye
```

But now if I want to access the db via `node.js` it doesn't work anymore, I get a `TypeError`.

I try this code (**UPDATED**):

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("connected!");
});
```

This is based on the npm module `mongodb`, I also tried `mongoose` and `mongojs`, each time with the same result. As soon as I want to connect to the database, I get a `TypeError`.

```
$ node mngclient.js 
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

events.js:172
    throw TypeError('type must be a string');
          ^
TypeError: type must be a string
    at TypeError (<anonymous>)
    at EventEmitter.once (events.js:172:11)
    at Server.Base._registerHandler (/home/odi/dev/mydb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:387:23)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/odi/dev/mydb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:410:12)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/odi/dev/mydb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:111:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:97:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/odi/dev/mydb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:297:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:116:20)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:848:10)
```

---

**UPDATE**:

- The version of the `mongodb` npm package is 1.3.23
- `npm outdated` shows no output, so I guess my packages are up-to-date
- Using `mongoose` with the following very simple code brings up the exact same error:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
```

---

**UPDATE II**:

- I still couldn't resolve this issue on my machine
- I setup the whole project in a virtual machine using vagrant. It works like a charm.

Comment: Unrelated but may I introduce you to Mongoose? :) http://mongoosejs.com

Comment: The answer provided shows you the `correct` connection string syntax and calling connect from MongoClient. Ignore the comment about starting a server in the answer. You basically seem to be trying to mix up an old legacy example of code with the new MongoClient class usage.

Comment: @NeilLunn okay I updated my example code, but still got the same result: it throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: Just wondering and again better to edit your question with the output / findings. What do you get from running `npm-outdated`. If things are showing up, try upgrading them. Especially anything mongo.

Comment: @NeilLunn `npm outdated` shows no output, so I guess all my packages are up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the document , your trying to start a server(I'm not sure why?) here is an example on connecting to the mongo database you already have running :

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:21017/myDb', function(err, db) {
  "use strict";
  if(err) throw err;
  ...//your code
});
```

Comment: Your assertion to use the URI syntax is correct but not the statement about starting a server.

Comment: apologies meant  local mongo data base !

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the result is still the same -> I get a `TypeError`.

Comment: Can you tell me your version of mongodb for node ?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: npm install mongodb
Step 2: create a file, name it suppose : app.js

Paste the following content into the file:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myDB';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  
    const db = client.db(dbName);
  
    insertDocuments(db, function() {
      client.close();
    });
  });

const insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
    // Get the documents collection
    const collection = db.collection('documents');
    // Insert some documents
    collection.insertMany([
      {a : 1}, {a : 2}, {a : 3}
    ], function(err, result) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      assert.equal(3, result.result.n);
      assert.equal(3, result.ops.length);
      console.log("Inserted 3 documents into the collection");
      callback(result);
    });
  }
```

Step 3 : node app.js

Step 4: run mongod and mongo, check updated db list using show dbs
Database will be created and a collection named 'documents' will be added over there.